# Using Ajax Service with variables

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a table grid
- clicking on the grid row i will display the full details about the selected row item
- during row click - variables initialized to default values
- service call made - variables assigned with corresponding data
- user can edit data and trigger save (have multiple service calls - final is the call to save)
- user can click on next record while save in progress

My issue is this 
- when user clicks on next record variables are initialized to default values
- when save is about to trigger variables are initialized or updated with the another record details

Need Solution
How to effectively handle the ajax service with variables?

Comment: Please share some code

Comment: Welcome, please read how to ask good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask